# How to read BindType prop from BindingSource?

Tags: .net, data-binding, c#-3.0

I'm looking for reading object type bind to **BindingSource**.

In debugger mode I've drilled down BndingSource object and I've found non-public property named "**BindType**" what contains interested info.

(Also found property "**ItemType**" what contains also such info - but I'm not sure it will work if BS.Count == 0)

Can you please advice how to read / access that info ?

Answer (score 0):

I've found solution myself - giving it here - maybe helps someone :)

```
    private static string ObjectHostedByBS (BocBindingSource bs) {
        if (bs == null) return string.Empty;


        ITypedList tl = bs as ITypedList;
        var a = tl.GetItemProperties(null);

        // no prop read
        if (a == null || a.Count == 0) return null;

        return a[0].ComponentType.Name;
    }
```